# AngularAMD loading module does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-amd

I'm trying to use angularAMD for a new project, but i can't get it to work.

i have the following:

**main.js**

```
require.config({
   baseUrl: "static/",
   paths: {
       'angular': 'bower_components/angular/angular',
       'angularAMD': 'bower_components/angularAMD/angularAMD',
       'ngload': 'bower_components/angularAMD/ngload',
       'ui-router': 'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router'
    },
    shim: {
       'ui-router': ['angular'],
       'angularAMD': ['angular'],
       'ngload': ['angularAMD']
    },
   deps: ['js/app']
});
```

**app.js**

```
define(['angularAMD', 'ui-router'], function (angularAMD) {
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui-router']);
    return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
});
```

**index.html script tag**

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="/static/js/main.js" src="/static/bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

The issue is that i keep getting the [Module Unavailable](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=ui-router) error.

I'm probably doing something wrong, but if i check the example on the angularAMD homepage my setup seems alright..

Hope someone can give me a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake with the module name i injected, it was supposed to be 'ui.router' instead of 'ui-router'.